# Oracle Max value via join two tables

Tags: oracle, view

Oracle Max value via join two tables what am I doing wrong?

tblKG:

```
KG_USER    KG_DATE    KG_TK_NO    KG_SQ_NO    KG_CNG_IND
---------------------------------------------------------
123456   200820     1           1           B
123456   200820     2           1           A
123456   200820     3           1           A
123456   200820     4           1           I
123456   200820     4           2           F
123456   200820     4           3           I
123456   200820     4           4           F
123456   200820     4           5           I
123456   200820     4           6           F
123456   200820     4           7           A
```

tblKN:

```
KN_USER    KN_DATE     KN_SQ_NO    KN_SEQ_NUMB
--------------------------------------------------
123456      200820      1           01
123456      200820      2           01
123456      200820      3           01
123456      200820      4           07
```

VIEW:

```
SELECT
        N.KN_DATE AS DATE,
        N.KN_USER AS USER,
        N.KN_SEQ_NO,    
        G.KG_TK_NO,
        G.KG_DATE,
        G.KG_USER,
        G.KGCNG_IND,                          
        G.MAX_SEQ_NO                              
 FROM               
        KN N,        
        (SELECT 
          KG_TK_NO, 
          KG_DATE,   
          KG_USER,       
          KG_CNG_IND AS KGCNG_IND,
          MAX(KG_SEQ_NO)  AS MAX_SEQ_NO        
     FROM
      KG
      GROUP BY KG_TK_NO, KG_DATE, KG_USER, KG_CNG_IND
    )  G
WHERE      
        N.KN_DATE = G.KG_DATE    
       AND N.KN_USER = G.KG_USER           
       AND N.KN_SEQ_NO = G.KG_TK_NO
```

RESULT:

```
DATE      USER        KN_SEQ_NO   KG_TK_NO    KGCNG_IND   MAX_SEQ_NO
200820  123456      1           1           B           1
200820  123456      2           2           A           1
200820  123456      3           3           A           1
200820  123456      4           4           A           7
200820  123456      4           4           F           6
200820  123456      4           4           I           5
```

Expected:

```
DATE      USER        KN_SEQ_NO   KG_TK_NO    KGCNG_IND   MAX_SEQ_NO
200820    123456      1           1           B           1
200820    123456      2           2           A           1
200820    123456      3           3           A           1
200820    123456      4           4           A           7
```

Comment: Sorry was KN did a copy paste from one of the other windows. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the maximum value, you use `MAX` and `GROUP BY`. But you don't really want that, you want to get **the row** with the maximum value.

For that, you need to rank the rows according to the column you are interested in, and then just use the first one.

```
SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT 
      KG_TK_NO, 
      KG_DATE,   
      KG_USER,       
      KG_CNG_IND,
      KG_SEQ_NO,
      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY KG_TK_NO, KG_DATE, KG_USER
                   ORDER BY KG_SEQ_NO DESC) AS R
  FROM KG)
WHERE R = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Suspect from your expected output you do not want fourth variable of GROUP BY.

```
GROUP BY KG_TK_NO, KG_DATE, KG_USER, ->KG_CNG_IND<-
```

and that you want MAX_SEQ_NO in this clause instead of G.KG_TK_NO

```
N.KN_SEQ_NO = G.KG_TK_NO
```

By the way, your column names are a little difficult to work with. I don't find the KG_ prefix style useful although it is popular. But the rest of the names are too short.

Comment: Sorry these were the names I was given. I need to output the cng_ind in the result.  Not sure if I follow.

Comment: You may want the cng_ind in the result, but it looks from your expected output that you do NOT want the cng_ind to matter in determining the MAX. instead you just want to bring it back in as a column for output once the 'winning' record has been determined. Angus's answer is a more sophisticated way of getting the winning row.